# Generating family details of the Employee

Tags: ms-access

Suppose I have multiple tables (say 3 for example) in access database. Lets name them as Employee, Spouse and Children. there is one to many relationship between Employee and Children table.

Employee has Name, Surname,DOB, Address, etc as an attributes while Spouse table and Children tables have also Name, Surname, DOB attributes. Employee table have more attributes than the other tables. They all have one primary attributes 'EmployeeID' that joins the tables.

Let's say I would like to design a query that will give me the whole family details of all the Company's employee, how should I do this please?

to clarify further, suppose EmployeeID 2345 have spouse with three children recorded in the database. Unlike any other joins, (the query should include all the rows from the Employee Table and all the corresponding records from other tables that match the attributes of Employee table) without repeating initial columns from the Employee Table. I.e. as follows.

EmplD   Name    Surname ....

2345 RAVI   COOK ....

2345 BANDANA    COOK ....

2345 SHANKEN    COOK ....

2345 SUSHANG    COOK  ....

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the employee number that you are searching to be a parameter ([search ID] below)?  You could use a Union query, something like

```
select EmplID, Name, Surname from [employees] where [EmplID]=[search ID]
union select EmplID, Name, Surname from  [spouses] where [EmplID]=[search ID]
union select EmplID, Name, Surname from  [children] where [EmplID]=[search ID];
```